# Node.js Ignoring blacklisted event 'disconnect'

Tags: node.js, networking, socket.io

```
$disc.submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
socket.emit('disconnect');
});
```

this code gives me the error   debug - ignoring blacklisted event 'disconnect'

why can't I call the disconnect function on the server from the client like I can call other socket functions?

Comment: Found your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730618/socket-io-server-very-delayed-in-registering-client-disconnects

Comment: But basically to avoid hostile/malicious callers from sending arbitrary IDs trying to disconnect them.